# React passing array from component to useState child (modal). Like to pass in as array and return it as array so can save

Tags: reactjs

I have the following parent React component. I would like to either pass the meeting.settings.ae (array of object) to the child useState Component. Don't know how I can fix it.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AEModal from "./AEModal";

export default class MAT extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ae: !!meeting.settings.ae ? meeting.settings.ae : ""
        };
    }

    getMeetingAEArray = () => {
        let setting = this.state.settings();
        return !!setting && !!setting.ae ? setting.ae : null;
    }

    getMeetingAE = () => {
        return <AEModal

            meeting={() => {
                return this.state.meeting;
            }}
            
            AEArray={() => {
                return getMeetingAEArray();
            }}
        />
    }
}
```

The child class

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import i18n from 'Components/translations/i18n';
import {
  Icon,
} from '@components';

function AEModal(props) {

  const [form, setForm] = useState([]);
  let meeting = props.meeting();
  let ae = meeting.settings.ae; //ae is undefined
  let aeArray = props.getAEArray();
}
```

Comment: So from where this `meeting` object coming from ?

Comment: And why do you need to pass an array from parent to child to save it inside child ? You can just keep your array inside your parent as a state. To change that state, create another method inside your parent and then pass it to the child component. From child component you can invoke that passed method.

Comment: HI @KavinduVIndika, You are right, I am new to React. I tried the update code above with the getMeetingAEArray method to pass along, but it does not work. Could you correct me how to pass the method along?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika The meeting is coming from its parent page. So AEModal is the third child.

Comment: Can you provide that parent as well ? You don't need to keep a state of the parent prop in each of the child component. You can just use it in all the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass props coming from parent, you can do it as follows.

Following is an example. Please modify it for your implementation.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AEModal from "./AEModal";

export default class MAT extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AEModal
        meeting={this.props.meeting}
      />
    );
  };
}
```

**Child component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function AEModal(props) {
  console.log("meeting: ", props.meeting);

  return <div>{props.meeting}</div>;
}
```